# Is it right to question the basic architecture of Tor?

Tags: discussion

On Tor beta I just posted a question about whether it is possible to avoid the final plaintext link beyond the exit nodes.

- Install something on the server that provides the hidden service

or

- Install a hidden service directly inside what looks like an exit node.

---

Another would be to force the hidden service to stay inside Tor entirely, to avoid getting caught by using Captcha on the clearnet within a hidden service.

---

So this question is whether this is the appropriate place to discuss fundamental changes of architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your question.
The StackExchange sites are thought to be Q&A sites which means a question leads to one or more answers. They're not for discussing things. There is a [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) where things can be discussed.

However if you want to make changes to Tor's architecture I'd recommend to get in touch with Tor's developers. That is either via [IRC](https://www.torproject.org/about/contact.html.en#irc) or via mail to [tor-dev@](https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/tor-dev). Both ways allow you to discuss your ideas directly and to get feedback from developers.